# Para que serve a opção "url" no arquivo de configuração app/config/app.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

No `Laravel 4`, temos um arquivo de configuração `app/config/app.php`.

Lá tem uma opção chamada `url`. Muitas vezes já vi essa opção vazia:

```
'url' => '',
```

E também já fiz o teste de colocar alguma url lá:

```
'url' => 'http://meusite.com'
```

Porém percebi que isso não mudou os links da minha aplicação. Isso acontecia no `Laravel 3`.

Sendo assim, qual é a finalidade dessa opção `url` no arquivo `app/config/app.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Até onde eu sei, essa configuração tem a finalidade de definir qual é a url base da aplicação quando não é possível detectá-la automaticamente.

Um exemplo básico disso é a execução na linha de comando.

Considere o seguinte exemplo utilizando o comando `tinker` (Laravel na linha de comando em modo iterativo) do `artisan`.

Primeiro deixo o arquivo de configuração `app/config/app.php` dessa forma:

```
// Outras definições ...

'url' => ''
```

Aí eu faço isso na linha de comando:

```
php artisan tinker --env=local

> URL::to('/test');
```

O resultado retornado é : `'/test'`

Agora, alteramos o arquivo de configuração novamente. Dessa vez colocarei uma url padrão.

Exemplo:

```
// Outras definições ...

'url' => 'http://stackoverflow.com.br/',
```

Rodamos o `tinker` novamente :

```
php artisan tinker --env=local

> URL::to('/test');
```

O resultado é: `'http://stackoverflow.com.br/test'`;

Então, perceba que, na falta de uma "url base" para o sistema, o `Laravel` usará essa url definida em `app/config/app.php` como a url base.